# Inner and outer paths of a stroke

Tags: android, graphics

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.quadTo(100, 0, 200, 200);
// more quadTo calls

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
```

From the path used to draw the stroke, is there a way to compute the inner and outer paths, in red and blue on the picture below ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... 
How about:
1. draw double width stroke first, then draw fill
2. clip path, then draw double width stroke